# IIS7 Certificate recovery

Tags: iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

One of my servers has just failed. I am unable to get it to boot.

I have built a replacement server on new hardware, but I have just discovered that the SSL cerrtificate we purchased through VeriSign was never exported.

I have the .cer file and the signing request but not the .pfx file to import to the new server.

I have the drives from the failed server that I can access.

Is there any way I can retrieve this certificate?

Thanks

Comment: Will VeriSign not reissue the certificate?

Comment: I wasn't aware that they would as this has never happened. I just discovered they will and am doing this right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll see from BitCareTech's comment, VeriSign and other CA's will re-issue the certificate.

+1 for BitCareTech

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, you should contact VeriSign for re-issue your certificate. While re-issue you will need to use newly generate CSR and install certificate again. You can only use re-issued certificate for same domain only.

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index.html

visit above link there you will find Chat With a Support Rep.

Chat with VeriSign Support team and ask assistance for re-issue certificate.

[Cheap EV SSL Certificates](https://www.thesslstore.com)
[Join SSL Reseller Program](https://www.thesslstore.com/join-reseller.aspx) 
[SSL Affiliate](http://affiliate.thesslstore.com)